# How to change cell color based on retrieved php value?

Tags: php, html, sql, colors, datatables

I'm trying myself on a personal project outside of school and try to create a table which adjusts the color of the table cells based on the retrieved value from the DB

1-3 = red
4-6 = yellow
7-10 - green

(All values are between 1 and 10)

I tried Jqueries and other examples from this page but can't apply it to my own code. Any help or hint is highly appreciated!!

My PHP code:

```
$content = "";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  
  require_once("db.php");  
  
  $date = $_POST["date"];
  
  $query = 
    "SELECT p.first_name,tf.intensity,tf.focus,tf.evaluation,tf.feedback
    FROM player p 
    INNER JOIN training_feedback tf ON p.player_id = tf.player_id
    WHERE tf.date = ? ";  
  
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);  
  
  $stmt->execute([$date]);  
  
  foreach($stmt as $row)  {
    
    $content .= 
    "<tr>
        <td>{$row["first_name"]}</td>
        <td>{$row["intensity"]}</td>
        <td>{$row["focus"]}</td>
        <td>{$row["evaluation"]}</td>
        <td>{$row["feedback"]}</td> 
     </tr>"; 
  } 
  
  $content =
"<h5>Training Feedack Creighton Goalkeepers:</h5>   
  <table>     
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Intensity</th>
        <th>Focus</th>
        <th>Evaluation</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
    </tr> 
  {$content}
  </table>";

}?>
```

````
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Training feedback</title>
    <link href= "main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div method="post">
      <h3>Training Feedback</h3>
      <form method="post">
        <div>
          <label>Date</label>
          <input type="date" name="date">
        </div>
        <div>
           <input type="submit"name="submit">
        </div>
      </form>
    <div><?php echo $content; ?></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Just set the CSS color

Comment: but if I set the css color of the cell i.e green, red, yellow it stays like this regardless of what value is retrieved??

Comment: Which field(s) do you want to add color to? Intensity?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to set the CSS color attribute. I will show it with simple example. Let's suppose you have a variable $var like so:

```
<?php
   $var = 7;
?>
```

Now you have a table row (<tr> tag) and you want to change its background color to red if $var is less than or equal to 3, yellow if $var is less than or equal to 6 or green if $var is more or equal to 7. Here is how you can do it:

```
<tr style="background-color:<?=($var<=3)?'red':(($var<=6)?'yellow':'green')?>">
```

What I do here is that I use the PHP echo operator (<?= is basically opening a PHP tag and echoing whatever the command after it outputs). Then I use the ternary operators (nested, not good for readability but it's short enough for a quick example) to see in which condition we fall with the value of $var. Whatever the operator outputs will be thrown to the echo command and PHP will print it in the html code.

Comment: Thank you! Where would you add this part? To the php code or has a header in the html part? I tried it with the php code, however get an syntax error code : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'background' (T_STRING)

Comment: You should not paste it within <?php ... ?> tags. It's directly for HTML code. In your case it will be something like this:
            $var=7;
     $content .= 
   "<tr style='background-color:".($var<=3)?'red':(($var<=5)?'yellow':'green').
   '>";

Comment: <tr style="background-color:<?=($content<=3)?'red':(($content<=6)?'yellow':'green')?>">

I added this at the top of my HTML code from above. $content is the reference which retrieves the numbers from my DB based on my query. The table still works however the cells remain white. The issue is that I can't define $var or in my case $content = 7 because its up to the customer what value they for example store in the DB under  <td>{$row["focus"]}</td> .

Comment: I would not do this inline - I’d give it a class and color using a class

Comment: Paul - then use $row["focus"] instead of $var.